# Angular 5 http error but not using http anymore

Tags: angular, http, httpclient

i have a issue with my angular V5 project.
I try to upgrade my version so, after replacing all the http, requestOptions etc reference by the new HttpClient, All works great.

But when i try to remove the HttpModule reference of my `shared.module.ts` i have an error and the application don't start.

This is the error:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
at _NullInjector.get (core.js:923)
at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10584)
at _createClass (core.js:10621)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10595)
```

I don't understand why the error talk about StaticInjectorError[Http] because i'm not using the Http module anywhere.

thanks you for your ideas!

Comment: After all you have pruivate http:Http somewhere.

Comment: No i didnt use http anymore. I have try a global search ans just one result in the shared.module.ts